# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS-goes standby continuously

Tags: power-management

my Laptop Toshiba Satellite Pro A300 works ok on Win Vista 64 and various Linux distros (Centos6, Slackware). I recently updated to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS(dual boot with Vista), but as soon as the OS starts (right after ubuntu splash) it goes in standby(suspend, like when someone presses the power switch once, everything turns off, the OS then can resume pressing the power ON button), if I re-turn it ON with the power switch, after about 10 seconds it goes again in standby and goes on in this cycle forever.
Any idea? I already checked the forum and other sites, but nothing. Maybe an issue with acpi? 
Thx

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly describe the behavior you see when "it goes in standby." The term "standby" means different things to different people, so it's not clear what you are seeing.

Comment: It looks like you have a removable battery, so try this... remove the battery, remove the DC power-in cable, press and hold the power button for 10-15 seconds. Reconnect the battery and DC power, and retest. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Also try this... boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start `terminal`, type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` (or manually enter the BIOS and locate the BIOS version). Give me that info, along with your complete model #.

Comment: The Toshiba web site doesn't appear to list a specific BIOS version, so download their "Service Station" software from https://support.dynabook.com/support/driversOSResults?freeText=1200012969 and run it.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn ' t work, I will try with a live cd.  I wonder why it works on a ubuntu 18.04 live and not the same imagine installed in the hd.

Comment: Solved at last, my fault. I created a user with name 'sys' which in some way caused a confusion in the system. I just formatted and reinstall eberything. Now it s ok.